# What actions are taken by linux before it successfully call to start_kernel()?

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, bootstrapping

I'm learning linux kernel internals and I understand that the first C function called is start_kernel(). But I think that the system must prepare itself to be able to run c functions, like installing the interupt service rutines.

Well, What are the full steps sequence that linux run? Where can I find it's code? (I'm using ubuntu 12.04 LTS with kernel 3.2.0.37-generic)

Answer (score 1):

Before calling the `start_kernel()` whole process go through the complete booting [process](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/linux/9780132396554/a-peek-inside-the-kernel/ch02lev1sec1).

Also in book ["Essential Linux Device Drivers"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEAQFjAC&url=http://wusewj-linux-books.googlecode.com/files/Essential%2520Linux%2520Device%2520Drivers%255B2008,851p%255D.pdf&ei=KLIwUcuDIoWHrAea5IGAAg&usg=AFQjCNGW_o5jLL6mYCVhHWnC0XZxujGQwg&bvm=bv.43148975,d.d2k) go the chapter "A Peek Inside the Kernel". Its author's [site.](http://www.elinuxdd.com/)

Also you can go through this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process).

Answer (score 1):

Before running the start_kernel (init/main.c) , there are some assembly code (for eg. head.S) which runs and prepares the system to run c function.

Interrupt service routines are done later.